# Memory Error with Multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, memory, multiprocessing

I'm trying to perform some costly scientific calculation with Python. I have to read a bunch of data stored in csv files and process then. Since each process take a long time and I have some 8 processors to use, I was trying to use the `Pool` method from `Multiprocessing`.

This is how I structured the multiprocessing call:

```
    pool = Pool()
    vector_components = []
    for sample in range(samples):
        vector_field_x_i = vector_field_samples_x[sample]
        vector_field_y_i = vector_field_samples_y[sample]
        vector_component = pool.apply_async(vector_field_decomposer, args=(x_dim, y_dim, x_steps, y_steps,
                                                                           vector_field_x_i, vector_field_y_i))
        vector_components.append(vector_component)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    vector_components = map(lambda k: k.get(), vector_components)

    for vector_component in vector_components:
        CsvH.write_vector_field(vector_component, '../CSV/RotationalFree/rotational_free_x_'+str(sample)+'.csv')
```

I was running a data set of 500 samples of size equal to 100 (**x_dim**) by 100 (**y_dim**).

Until then everything worked fine.

Then I receive a data set of 500 samples of 400 x 400.

When running it, I get an error when calling the `get`.

I also tried to run a single sample of 400 x 400 and got the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    VfD.samples_vector_field_decomposer(samples, x_dim, y_dim, x_steps, y_steps, vector_field_samples_x, vector_field_samples_y)
  File "/export/home/pceccon/VectorFieldDecomposer/Sources/Controllers/VectorFieldDecomposerController.py", line 43, in samples_vector_field_decomposer
    vector_components = map(lambda k: k.get(), vector_components)
  File "/export/home/pceccon/VectorFieldDecomposer/Sources/Controllers/VectorFieldDecomposerController.py", line 43, in <lambda>
    vector_components = map(lambda k: k.get(), vector_components)
  File "/export/home/pceccon/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 554, in get
    raise self._value
MemoryError
```

What should I do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you run out of free ram?

Comment: It seems to be that, now that you mentioned (I'm running this through ssh).

Comment: What do you want to do with the contents of `vector_components` once you have it fully populated? Your sample size right now appears to be too big to fit in memory, so you're going to have to only keep part of it in memory at a time.

Comment: Well then you got only 3 solutions - smaller data set/break your data into chunks and process them independenly/get more ram

Comment: I would like to save each one of them (in another csv) since they are processed. I can do that using Pool in Python?

Comment: Yes. Give me a few minutes to write an answer :)

Comment: Thank you. (: However, I got this error even running a single sample of 400 x 400. I bet you answer this would help me a lot, but I'll still have to reduce my data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right now you're keeping several lists in memory - `vector_field_x`, `vector_field_y`, `vector_components`, and then a separate copy of `vector_components` during the `map` call (which is when you actually run out of memory). You can avoid needing either copy of the `vector_components` list by using [`pool.imap`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.imap), instead of `pool.apply_async` along with a manually created list. `imap` returns an iterator instead of a complete list, so you never have all the results in memory.

Normally, `pool.map` breaks the iterable passed to it into chunks, and sends the those chunks to the child processes, rather than sending one element at a time. This helps improve performance. Because `imap` uses an iterator instead of a list, it doesn't know the complete size of the iterable you're passing to it. Without knowing the size of the iterable, it doesn't know how big to make each chunk, so it defaults to a `chunksize` of 1, which will work, but may not perform all that well. To avoid this, you can provide it with a good `chunksize` argument, since you know the iterable is `sample` elements long. It may not make much difference for your 500 element list, but it's worth experimenting with.

Here's some sample code that demonstrates all this:

```
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial


def vector_field_decomposer(x_dim, y_dim, x_steps, y_steps, vector_fields):
    vector_field_x_i = vector_fields[0]
    vector_field_y_i = vector_fields[1]
    # Do whatever is normally done here.


if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_workers)
    # Calculate a good chunksize (based on implementation of pool.map)
    chunksize, extra = divmod(samples // 4 * num_workers)
    if extra:
        chunksize += 1

    # Use partial so many arguments can be passed to vector_field_decomposer
    func = partial(vector_field_decomposer, x_dim, y_dim, x_steps, y_steps)
    # We use a generator expression as an iterable, so we don't create a full list.
    results = pool.imap(func, 
                        ((vector_field_samples_x[s], vector_field_samples_y[s]) for s in xrange(samples)),
                        chunksize=chunksize)
    for vector in results:
        CsvH.write_vector_field(vector_component, 
                                '../CSV/RotationalFree/rotational_free_x_'+str(sample)+'.csv')
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

This *should* allow you to avoid the `MemoryError` issues, but if not, you could try running `imap` over smaller chunks of your total sample, and just do multiple passes. I don't think you'll have any issues though, because you're not building any additional lists, other than the `vector_field_*` lists you start with.